# Jasmine/Protractor, have a shared beforeAll method

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'd like to have a shared `beforeAll()` methods across all my test suites. Is there a way to do it? (I mean, without writing the same `beforeAll/afterAll` methods in all the test suites)

Thanks,

Comment: should it be called once before all suites or once before every suite?

Comment: once before every suite

Comment: You can place operation in onPrepare() method in config file. it would be called once per capability.

Comment: Suresh it won't be called before each suite but once before the entire run session.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a reusable beforeAll method that appears in all your spec files. You will still have to pass the function `somefile.beforeAll` to the jasmine `beforeAll` method in the example below:

somefile.js

```
exports.beforeAll = function() {
  // cool stuff here.
}
```

spec.js

```
var somefile = require('./path/to/somefile');

describe('some cool browser thing', function() {

  // instead of beforeAll(function() { });
  // send in your function here.
  beforeAll(somefile.beforeAll);

});
```

If you need to do this once before all spec files, think about using [plugins](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/plugins.ts#L23).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any task runner like gulp, you may define a beforeAll function and wrap it inside a gulp task and call before  each suite task internally as prerequisite task as below:

```
gulp.task('SuiteA', ['BeforeAll'], function () { 
  executeSuiteA_Tests('parameters'); // before calling this 'BeforeAll' task will be called
});
```